# Trouble with facebook sdk quickstart

Tags: facebook

Following directions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

I started with a mostly blank HTML page, just the HTML, Body tags, and a simple Hello World.

I copied and pasted directly from the quickstart page but get nothing (but Hello World does Load).
I have an app ID (I wasn't sure if I should include the {} or not, tried both ways, no change.
I added the code from section "Using the SDK to add Social Plugins", "Using the SDK to trigger a Feed dialog" etc and nothing.  Running on CentOS/Apache, server is fine.  Not sure what I'm missing.  Thoughts?
Thank you for your time.

PS page is here to view source: http://nex916.elementfx.com/purity3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following will be of help?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

    <!-- Load the Facebook JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Initialize the Facebook JavaScript SDK
      FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
      });

      // Check if the current user is logged in and has authorized the app
      FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);

      // Login in the current user via Facebook and ask for email permission
      function authUser() {
        FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'email'});
      }

      // Check the result of the user status and display login button if necessary
      function checkLoginStatus(response) {
        if(response && response.status == 'connected') {
          //alert('User is authorized');

          // Hide the login button
          document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'none';

          // Now Personalize the User Experience
          //console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
        } else {
          //alert('User is not authorized');

          // Display the login button
          document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
          FB.ui(
      {
       method: 'feed',
       name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
       caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
       description: (
          'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
          'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
          'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
       ),
       link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
       picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
    );
    </script>
    <input id="loginButton" type="button" value="Ligin with Facebook" onclick="authUser();" /></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: I copied the code and dumped it into a new file, https://secure.regionix.org/travis/purity2.html    It makes a button, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: As Adam Azad said in a comment on his own answer your App is not configured correctly, check your URLs? as I get the Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.

Comment: wow, I was only looking at in chrome .. (yes, I know, fail).  I opened it in FF and it seems to work.  Thanks.

Comment: It should also work in chrome, you could try clearing the browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your JS

> SyntaxError: syntax error purity2.html:26

To fix it, remove `};` from `line 19`

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log('Logged in');
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
}; // this
```

it should be like

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log('Logged in');
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
```

Now your code should work

Comment: I had just copied the code from the quickstart page, but I think that extra }; is the closing of the window.fbAsyncInit call.  Even after fixing that, still nothing.  I went back and removed that login part to simplify.  As is, it should show the fb-like div, but doesn't.  Thoughts?  thanks for replying.

Comment: It's showing the `FB-Like` button, but you haven't configured your app

Comment: wow, I was only looking at in chrome .. (yes, I know, fail).  I opened it in FF and it seems to work.  Thanks.