# Cannot Run Facebook SDK Scripts in Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to use Facebook's Javascript SDK to perform some actions. I am following the instructions provided in Facebook's JDK documentation.

Accordingly, I have the following code in my html file:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<the ID of my app>',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          alert('Logged in');
        } else {

          FB.login();
        }
      });
    };
    </script>
```

I am trying to check if the user is logged in and, if they are not, do a user login. Note that I am using an alert box to tell if I am logged in, and another to tell if I am not.

When I display my page, it looks like the scripts are not running.

Am I missing something? The Facebook instructions do nt say to do anything special to start the scripts. Should I be doing something that they are not mentioning?

Someone please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546473/trouble-with-facebook-sdk-quickstart/22547133#22547133

Comment: Thanks, Malcolm. My script is now running, at least...

Comment: Almost forgot: The code with the syntax error -- I downloaded it from Facebook's web site! Somebody needs to talk to those people...

Comment: Glad you got it running, I agree when it comes to the Facebook docs they are not always up to date.